# Geometrical Function Thoery

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

i have problem in understanding the modulus of $f'(z)$. Please explain the geometrical interpretation of $|f'(z)|$.

Comment: Two relevant links: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745756/geometrical-meaning-of-derivative-of-complex-function), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905731/physical-or-geometric-meaning-of-complex-derivative)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physical or geometric meaning of complex derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905731/physical-or-geometric-meaning-of-complex-derivative)